# Cakephp JS helper with jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, datepicker

I switched from select boxes to the jQuery datepicker with Cakephp 2.3.8 and I'm wondering if there's a way that I can trigger a POST request with the JS helper when the date is selected. I send POST request to look up values for that specific date. I know it can be done with just jQuery/AJAX, but if I can use the JS helper I'd prefer that since I already have it implemented from when I used the select boxes.

For example, the request will be triggered when the input is clicked, but not when a date is actually selected

```
$this->Js->get('#arrival_date')->event('click', //also tried change
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'registration',
        'action'=>'room_number'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#RegistrationRoomId',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
);
```

I know I can get it to work with something like this, but since I switched to the datepicker from just using select boxes for the date, I already have everything else implemented for the JS helper. The only issue is getting the JS helper to trigger when a value is selected.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input.datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(date){
                check_availability(date);
            },
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            yearRange: "-100:+50",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: false,
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
});


function check_availability(date){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the datepicker still lies an `input` element having all the normal events an input has.

So the events `onchange` or `onblur` (depending on what you want to do) will do the job if you bind one of those to the needed action instead of `onclick`.